# How do we know that anything is contingent?

Tags: contingent

From what I gather, the idea of a contingent event means that it could have been otherwise. But since we can’t play back the universe, how do we know that it could have been otherwise?

Note that by contingent, I mean metaphysically contingent, not logically contingent. Of course, I can imagine a 15 foot human, but it doesn’t mean it is possible.

Even in a universe with no determinism, is it possible for events in the universe, perhaps even for no reason, to play out in only one way possible? Why or why not?

Comment: If we suppose that conceivability is not identical to imaginability, then we might assimilate logical possibility to the one, metaphysical possibility to the other, and then since, "A fifteen-foot-tall human," is not self-contradictory and can also be visualized, it is both logically and metaphysically possible, perhaps. If our thought experiment is of a world without determinism as *nomological* necessity and hence nomological possibility (then nomological modality in general), perhaps mere imaginability counts as evidence of metaphysical alternative possibilities, here.

Comment: "Possibility" regarding contingency and necessity means "metaphysical possibility", not "possibility according to natural laws" or something like this.

Comment: The same way we know anything, without absolute certainty and keeping it open to future revision. If our best theories of metaphysical possibility designate something as contingent then so it is, for now. No need to play back the universe, playing back its models suffices. But there is plenty of debate as to what is best considered metaphysically contingent even as it is, see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/#MetNomMod).

Answer (score 1):

1. Definition: See "Robert Audi (Ed.): The Cambridge Dictionary of
   Philosophy":

   > **contingent**, neither impossible nor necessary, i.e. both possible and
   > non-necessary. The modal property of being contingent is attributable
   > to a proposition, state of affairs, event, or – more debatably – an
   > object.

   For abbreviation I will use the term object as a generic term,
   covering proposition, state of affairs and event.

   Employing the ontology of possible worlds an object is contingent if
   it exists in at least one possible world but not in all possible
   worlds. In particular, if it exists in our real world but not in all
   possible worlds, then it is contingent.

   The question of the OP does not deal with the contingency of
   propositions.
2. How to determine whether real objects other than propositions are
   contingent?

   I agree that the general answer “check that it could
   have been different” does not work, because as you say “we can’t
   play back the universe”. The general answer is sometimes erroneously
   considered an argument for free will. This shows the diffculty to
   make the definition operable.

   One possibility is to equate
   contingency with being undetermined. And to move the question to the
   field of science. Here it is not enough to state “we do no know any
   cause”, but one has to argue why there is no cause. In this sense, according to the
   Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics all single events of
   the microsmos are undetermined, i.e. contingent.

   On the opposite,
   there are successful deterministic theories about events in the
   macroscopic realm, e.g., Newtons’s mechanics and its refinements
   concerning the movement of the planets in the solar system.

   Hence I
   consider events observed in microphysics to be contingent, while
   events explained by a deterministic theory to be not-consistent.

   Eventually, if one someone points to events which are non-determined
   but can play out in a possible universe in only one way, this fact
   would be a prompt for further research.

Comment: Your definition 1 is begging the question. A possible non-actual world is just a world in which the contingent things could have been different.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Could you please explain your objection; thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. You used possible worlds to explain what contingency is, but the concept of possible worlds itself relies on the notion of contingency. It's circular.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I use the definition(!) from the Cambridge Dictionary, and I use the concept of possible worlds as an illustration(!) of the definition. - But even when using the concept of possible words as a definition, I do not see a circularity.

Comment: We are in our cars and meet in a crossroad. One will pass and the other will follow;: non-determined, but can play out in only one way; in the sense that both cars cannot pass simultaneously.

Comment: +1. Good answer. I see nothing wrong with definition 1 -- it is a core piece of modal logic, hardly a fringe area of philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

> How do we know that anything is contingent?

Do we know anything about the world outside our mind?

Apparently not, but we do have beliefs, and we may even have rational beliefs, that is, beliefs based on our empirical experience of the world and on logic.

We accordingly interpret events in terms of causes and effects. For instance, rain causes the effect that the ground becomes wet. According to our experience, without the rain, the ground would still by dry.

Do we know this? No, we don't, but nobody cares. What matters is that most people believe that this is true, presumably because there is just one reality and that we therefore can only all share broadly the same experience of it.

We also say in this case that the ground becoming wet is *contingent* on the rain falling on the ground.

This is all there is to it. This is just a definition. But it is a definition for something that most people believe is true based on their empirical experience of the world and on logic. The rest is metaphysics.

Answer (score 0):

We don't, it's just a belief; a philosophical claim.

Leucippus believed that "**nothing occurs without a cause, but all occur from a logical force and from ανάγκη**". ανάγκη means "something that is enforced to us that we cannot avoid" and not "necessity" as it is commonly translated.

The Stoics believed that "**everything is done according to ειμαρμένη**". ειμαρμένη means "that which determines under what terms an event is going to happen.

(Besides them this concept of "ανάγκη" was a fundamental one among all major Greek philosophers)

We could call this something like physical necessity (similarities with actualism); in this sense, it is obvious that these views are opposite to contingency.

Later on (by modern philosophers), these thesis were abandoned - as describing reality - and were considered valid only in the field of defining logic and mathematical foundations.

So, ... things led to contingency as a representation of reality. To my understanding, what happened was that it was considered that we could "free" ourselves out of some constrains so to speak and consider reality more like something we can play with or mould to our needs; a socio-political factor you could say.

I think the bottom line of this or the other "view of reality" is a matter of how one identifies himself in accordance with others and nature. It's a philosophical aspect with huge implications in personal life, societies and politics. Contingency vs "ανάγκη" (Necessity) is in fact a matter of ontology with theological ramifications.

Answer (score 0):

We can't know for certain that a system is behaving randomly.

What we can do is try and discover a pattern, a rule that allows us to predict the outcome. If we don't find one, or if all we can find is a probabilistic pattern, we conclude -- at least temporarily -- that the system is behaving randomly.

In other words, by default we try to look for some way to predict the outcome. It's only when that fails that we conclude to randomness.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination is to consider your question to be ill founded. Whether something is contingent is a matter of definition. There are certain things that have to be so, given the context in which they exist or happen. Objects on Earth have to be attracted to the ground by gravity. If you want to say that everything has to have been the way it was because that's how the Universe has played out, then you are free to view it that way, and by your definition everything would be necessary- but you would be using the word 'necessary' in an idiosyncratic way. You would not have invalidated the usual distinction between necessary and contingent- instead you have chosen to ignore it by adopting a different definition of the labels.